# Mapping values to array of items to fill missing object properties?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, dictionary

in JS I have an array of items, every item has this form:

```
{
  id: 'fa4da51',
  name: 'product-name',
  prettyName: 'Product Name',
  price: null,
}
```

I run map on the array and then return `item.price` to display the price of every item.

Some of the items I'm getting from external API have no prices (`price` set to `null`). The items in API won't change in the future, the ids might, but not names.

I came up with an idea that if `!item.price` then let's show the fallback price for given item.

What would be the best approach to get what I want?

I've been thinking about creating a Map for every item (just in case) like so:

```
var itemPrices = new Map([
   ['product-name', 100],
   ['product-name-2', 200],
   ['product-name-3', 300],
]);
```

And then doing: `item.price ?? item.price || itemPrices[item.name]`.

Is this a good approach for about 5000 items? Out of those roughly 1500 have no prices. Can I tweak it somehow to make it more performant? Does the thing I want to achieve have some kind of standardised name so I could Google it? The man responsible for the API is on a really long sick leave and I have to hotfix this without access to the back-end.

Thank you for any hints.

Comment: Your proposed solution sounds fine to me, you can actually just return `item.price ?? itemPrices.get(item.name)`